# bash script: execute a command and pass its output to awk

Tags: bash, awk, cluster-computing

I'm having issues with a bash script. Basically, in my script I run the command

```
bjobs -u $1
```

$1 is the script argument, and it's the id of a user on my cluster. If user $1 has no running/pending jobs on the cluster, bjobs prints

```
 No unfinished jobs found
```

to stdout. Also, exit status is 255. If user $1 does have jobs, bjobs print:

```
JOBID   USER    STAT  QUEUE      FROM_HOST   EXEC_HOST   JOB_NAME   SUBMIT_TIME
45823   .......
45824   .......
.
.
```

and exit status is 0. I would like awk to parse the output of bjobs. I tried

```
bjobs -u $1 | awk '...'
```

where '...' is my awk parsing program. This doesn't work so well, because apparently when user $1 doesn't have running/pending jobs, the string "No unfinished jobs found" is ***not*** passed to awk. The same happens with

```
bjobs -u $1 > foo
awk '...' foo
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does `bjobs` send the message to stdout really? Does not it go to stderr?

Comment: Hi, @choroba , yes, it looks like bjobs sends the message "No unfinished jobs found" to stderr, while when it founds jobs, it writes to stdout. So redirecting stderr to stdout solved the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe that message (being an error of sorts, I guess) is coming to STDERR not STDOUT.

You can redirect IO streams in bash with > to file descriptors, and 2 is STDERR.

Try:

```
bjobs -u $1 2>&1 | awk '...'
```

And see if that solves it for you. The 2>&1 part means redirect STDERR (2) to STDOUT (1), and STDOUT is what is piped into awk.

More info: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Answer (score 1):

It is possible bjobs prints "No unfinished jobs found" to the stderr.

Add 2>&1 to pipe stderr to stdout.

[More info on bash IO redirection](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html)